# Function if not working not getting desire value

Tags: excel, vba

I want to update Cell "D6" based on Range ("N11:N35")

- If all of Range ("N11:N35") is Blank than Cell "D6" needs to be ""
  (Blank)
- If all of Range ("N11:N35") is filled than Cell "D6" needs to
  "Completed"
- If only some of Range ("N11:N35") is filled than Cell "D6"
  needs to be "In Process"

```
    If WorksheetFunction.CountA(Range("N11:N35")) = 0 Then
        ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Check List").Range("D8") = "Complete "
    Else
        ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Check List").Range("D8") = "In Process"
    End If
```

Comment: If you `debug.print WorksheetFunction.CountA(Range("N11:N35"))` what results do you get for each of your desired outputs? (I.e. do you get 0 when expecting 0, do you get 1 when expecting 1 etc.)

Comment: You just need an `ElseIf` to check and default for a third condition. See my answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this, I'm using `CountBlank` to check for blank cells.

```
If WorksheetFunction.CountBlank(Range("N11:N35")) = 0 Then
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Check List").Range("D8") = "Complete "
ElseIf WorksheetFunction.CountBlank(Range("N11:N35")) = 25 Then
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Check List").Range("D8") = ""
Else
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Check List").Range("D8") = "In Process"
End If
```

Also note your question says cell "D6" but your code is pointing to "D8"

Answer (score 2):

Try this code, please:

```
Sub testRangeEvaluate()
 Dim sh As Worksheet, rng As Range
 Set sh = ActiveSheet 'use here the sheet you need
                      'it may be ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Check List")
 Set rng = sh.Range("N11:N35")
  If WorksheetFunction.CountA(rng) = 0 Then
    sh.Range("D6").Value = ""
  ElseIf WorksheetFunction.CountA(rng) = rng.Cells.Count Then
    sh.Range("D6").Value = "Completed"
  ElseIf WorksheetFunction.CountA(rng) > 0 And _
        WorksheetFunction.CountA(rng) < rng.Cells.Count Then
    sh.Range("D6").Value = "In Process"
  End If
End Sub
```

The code will work even if you will extend the range in discussion...

Answer (score 2):

does it work for you?

```
Private Sub Test()
    Dim iCountCells As Long
    iCountCells = Range("N11:N35").Cells.Count
    With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Check List")
        If WorksheetFunction.CountA(Range("N11:N35")) = iCountCells Then
            .Range("D8") = "Not started "
            Exit Sub
        End If
        If WorksheetFunction.CountA(Range("N11:N35")) = 0 Then
            .Range("D8") = "Complete "
        Else
            .Range("D8") = "In Process"
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

I would write you target code using a select case and also embed the test in a function.

```
Option Explicit

Public Function GetRangeStatus(ByVal ipRange As Range) As String
    
    Dim myBlankCount As Long
    myBlankCount = WorksheetFunction.CountA(ipRange)
    
    Select Case myBlankCount
    
        Case Is = 0
        
            GetRangeStatus = "Completed"
        
        Case Is = ipRange.Rows.Count
        
            GetRangeStatus = vbNullString
            
        Case Else
        
            GetRangeStatus = "In Process"
            
    End Select
    
End Function
```

So you can now say

```
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Check List").Range("D8")=GetRangeStatus("Range("N11:N35"))
```